# Pointer Addition in K&R

Tags: c, malloc

In K&R's malloc() procedure, page 187:

```
 p->s.size -= nunits;
 p += p->s.size;
 p->s.size = nunits;
```

The first call to change the size of p also changes its size inside of prevp, its container pointer.  After the address addition, the second call changes only the size of p.  Does the += operation create a copy of p that can be manipulated without altering the initial p?

Comment: More context like the whole function would be appreciated.

Comment: No, the value `p` is overwritten by the `+=` operator, so the third line is using the updated value of `p`.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea is to reuse a previously freed block. The size of the block has been checked to be bigger than what nunits (the argument to the function nbytes plus some overhead)

```
// we need nunits bytes from the original free sized block
p->s.size -= nunits; 

// move the pointer size bytes forward 
p += p->s.size; 

// now we are at the block we want to return, set correct size.
p->s.size = nunits;
```

e.g.

the freed block has 100 bytes, nunits is 60 bytes so we want to use 60 bytes of that block and leave the 40 bytes for another malloc.

first we change remaining size to 40 (p->s.size = 40)
then we move the pointer 40 bytes forward (those 40 remain free)
now p points to the start of the block we will return, now we set the size of the allocated block (p->s.size = 60)

Comment: Thanks, my problem was with how the remaining unused memory was retained in the prevp/freep Header.  The p += p->s.size call not only moves the pointer but allows setting of p->s.size without affecting s.size for prevp.  Initially, however, p->s.size -= nunits does change the size of the prevp pointer as I run it through debugger.

Comment: it does not change the size of prevp pointer, it changes what it points to.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the `+=` operation create a copy of `p` that can be manipulated
>   without altering the initial `p`?

Answer: **No**. For example in `p += some_value`, the `+=` operator is equivalent to `p = p + some_value`. When using `+=` you will always alter the *lvalue*. Otherwise that would render the `+=` operator meaningless.

Comment: Thanks.  That helps.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. After you make friends with `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, look at `&=` and `|=` (which work the same way but with bitwise `&` and `|`) and then make sure you understand the *ternary* operator (`test ? true code : false code`) (e.g. `char *name = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "default_name";`). All will help you write your code much more fluently.

Comment: I've been slogging through the last code example in K&R and this was the last bit of their entire malloc/morecore/free example that I didn't quite get.  I understand += as an operator overall; the problem was with the pointer and how the operator replaced one pointer with another, in order to retain unused memory for the previous Header in the list.  Anyway, appreciate the help and advice.